# PHP Jquery ajax call returning html code does not work on server with 200 ok response ,but works on localhost

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a dependent dropdown for state,county and township in my webpage.php which has javascript function fetchcounties(state) and fetchtownship(county) which makes ajax calls depending on the values selected in the dropdown . The code works as expected on localhost but when i tried it on server it does not populate values . Response variable does not get value back from the ajax call on server .

**webpage.php**

```
    <select id="state" name="state" value="NA" onchange= "fetchcounties(this.value)">
        <option value="NA">Please Select a State</option>
          <?php   
             foreach($GLOBALS['states'] as $state)
            {

                echo '<option value="'.$state.'">'.$state.'</option>';
            }

            ?>

    <tr><td><b>County: </b></td>
        <td><select name="county" id="county" onchange= "fetchtownships(this.value)">
         <option value="NA">Please select a county</option> 
         </select></td>


     <tr><td><b>Township: </b></td><td> <select name="township" id="township"  >
         <option value="NA">Please select a township</option> 
        </select></td>
```

**Javascript function and ajax calls**

```
function fetchcounties(state){
        $.ajax({
                 url:"fetchcounty.php",
                 type: "post",
                 async:false,
                 data:{
                    'state':state
                    },
                 success: function(data) 
            {
                 $("#county").html(data);
                 fetchtownships($('#county').val());

            }});


    }

    function fetchtownships(county){

        $.ajax({
                 url:"fetchtownship.php",
                 type: "post",
                 async:false,
                 data:{
                    'county':county
                    },
                 success: function(data) 
            {
                 $("#township").html(data);
            }});


    }
```

**fetchcounty.php**

```
<?php


require('les_config.php');
$db = mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database ". mysql_error());

$states = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['state']);

//$states = mysql_real_escape_string($states);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT county from ZIP_CODE  where state ='$states'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$county = $row["county"];
echo '<option value="'.$county.'">'.$county.'</option>';
}

?>
```

**fetchtownship.php**

```
<?php


require('les_config.php');
$db = mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database ". mysql_error());

$county = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['county']);

//$states = mysql_real_escape_string($states);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT town from ZIP_CODE  where county ='$county'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$town = $row["town"];
echo '<option value="'.$town.'">'.$town.'</option>';
}
?>
```

Comment: are there different PHP versions running on your localhost vs your server?

Comment: In Windows, MySQL database and table names are not case-sensitive, whereas they are case-sensitive on Linux (what your server probably runs). Are you referencing table names in a case-sensitive manner in your queries?

Comment: Also, Linux has case-sensitive filename extensions (.jpg is different from .JPG, for example), whereas Windows is case-insensitive. So make sure the files you reference in your code have the correct extension.

Comment: `$db = mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);` you aren't using `localhost` while on the server are you? That would be the first obvious thing to check since it is in your posted code.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly the problem , my queries were not case sensitive .

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome or Firefox check out the Network tab to see what is happening. You should look to see that the request you expect is being made is actually happening. If it is, check the request URL is correct, check the response is correct. I suspect one of these things is not working which will help you narrow down where to look.

Comment: I did check as suggested on the chrome and firefox and i was not getting the response as i mentioned in the question . But i figured out what was the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, But i just realised that the problem was not with the ajax call but it was with SQL query . Learnt something today that SQL queries are Case sensitive on Server, need to take care of that . Problem resolved thanx again!